# Amsterdam travel tickets

Tags: trains, tickets, public-transport, amsterdam

I plan to go to Amsterdam in April, how can I purchase the Amsterdam travel Ticket for two days and have it started at Amsterdam airport?

Comment: Not a duplicate but helpful: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176301/ov-chipkaart-value-and-refunds-in-2022

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the link below answers your question:

https://www.schiphol.nl/en/page/amsterdam-travel-ticket/

> Visit [Discoverholland.com](https://Discoverholland.com) to buy your ticket online. You can also buy
> your ticket in person at AKO, Connexxion and at the yellow Service and
> Ticket Desk in Schiphol Plaza, the airport’s main foyer.